# Treeview how to select multiple rows using cursor up and down keys

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I've been trying to figure out what I need to do to select multiple rows in the treeview widget using the keyboard. I have tried all the different bindings and I can't seem to get anything to work correctly.
It seems my calls have no effect.

I have provied the code I'm using to test this I must be missing something!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview


class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.container = Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.tv = None
        self.tree()

        def shift_down(event):
            _widget = event.widget
            _focus = event.widget.focus()
            _widget.selection_add(_focus)
            print(_focus)

        self.tv.bind('<Shift-Down>', lambda e: shift_down(e))

    def tree(self):
        tv = self.tv = Treeview(self.container)
        tv.grid(sticky='NSEW')

        tv.insert('', '0', 'item1', text='Item 1', tags='row')
        tv.insert('', '1', 'item2', text='Item 2', tags='row')
        tv.insert('', '2', 'item3', text='Item 3', tags='row')

        tv.insert('item1', '0', 'python1', text='Python 1')
        tv.insert('item1', '1', 'python2', text='Python 2')

        tv.insert('python1', '0', 'sub1', text='Sub item 1')
        tv.insert('python1', '1', 'sub2', text='Sub item 2')


def main():
    root = Tk()

    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    App(root)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Relevant [how-to-change-selection-without-clicking-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115083/ttk-treeview-how-to-change-selection-without-clicking-first), [track-keyboard-selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359550/ttk-treeview-track-keyboard-selection)

Comment: I looked at the link you provided but there is nothing there of any help for what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to be able to select multiple rows while holding down the shift key and pressing up and down keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: select multiple rows using cursor up and down keys

---

> *"I have tried all the different bindings and I can't seem to get anything to work correctly. It seems my calls have no effect."*
>
> You want to **change standard behavior** of a `ttk.Treeview`.
>   Since your above binding applies to the instance level only,
>   and the standard behavior is provided by a class level bindings.
>   Therefore all your changes are reverted, thats why you see **no effect**.
>
> To prevent `Tkinter` from propagating the event to other handlers; just return the string `“break”` from your event handler:

---

- [Tk8.6.9 Documentation - ttk_treeview](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm)
- [Instance and Class Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

---

For example:
**Note**: Here, only `<Shift-Down>` is shown.

There is no need to use `lambda:`.

```
self.tv.bind('<Shift-Down>', shift_down)

def shift_down(event):
    tree = event.widget
    cur_item = tree.focus()

    # You need the next item, because you `"break"` standard behavior
    next_item = tree.next(cur_item)

    # Set the keyboard focus to the `next_item`
    tree.focus(next_item)

    # Add both items to the `selection` list
    tree.selection_add([cur_item, next_item])

    print('shift_down cur_item:{}\nselection:{}'\
        .format(cur_item, tree.selection()))

    # Stop propagating this event to other handlers!
    return 'break'
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***

Comment: Great just what I needed thank so much for that. I was really struggling on this and you have just enlighten me.